# Show image in viewpager that has the same id

Tags: android, image, arraylist, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

my app is click image on gridview and show it in viewpager. my database has two tables. tbl_cafe and tbl_pictures. tbl_cafe has stored id,title,desc and tbl_picture has stored cafe_id and pictures.

`ImagePagerActivity` I queried tbl_pictures and store in `<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`. ImagePagerActivity I used Universal Image Loader library for `Viewpager`. In ViewpagerActivity I queried image name and concatenated it with url for downloading image. 
at this time it shows all my images in my database.

I use different table that cause me stuck to show image in viewpager only the same id.

**What I want is, click image on my gridview in `TopActivity` after show image in Viewpager only image that has the same id.**

TopActivity

```
gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(TopActivity.this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_ID, position);
            i.putExtra(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_TITLE, position);
            i.putExtra(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_ADDRESS, position);
            i.putExtra(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_DESCRIPTION, position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

tbl_cafe & tbl_pictures

[image]

ImagePagerActivity Full for [ImagePagerActivity](http://pastie.org/7147004)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_pager);

    dataSource = new CafeDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();
    arrCursor = dataSource.getArrCursor();
    arrCursorPicture = dataSource.getArrCursorPicture();
    pagerPosition  = arrCursorPicture.size();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
    }   

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    arrImageUrl = getArrImageUrl();
    pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(arrImageUrl));
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);

} // End onCreate

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getArrImageUrl(){
    arrImageUrl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map;
    for (int i = 0; i < pagerPosition; i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        url = "http://xxx.xxx/xxx/place_pictures/"+arrCursorPicture.get(i).get(CafeDbOpenHelper.PICTURE_URL);
        map.put("image_url", url);
        arrImageUrl.add(map);
    }
    return arrImageUrl;

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    outState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, pager.getCurrentItem());
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    ImagePagerAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myArr) {
        this.myArr = myArr;
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myArr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.imv_pager);
        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        imageLoader.displayImage((String) myArr.get(position).get("image_url"), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason.getType()) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case DECODING_ERROR:
                        message = "Image can't be decoded";
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_DENIED:
                        message = "Downloads are denied";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you even trying to do here?

```
        i.putExtra(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_ID, position);
        i.putExtra(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_TITLE, position);
        i.putExtra(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_ADDRESS, position);
        i.putExtra(CafeDbOpenHelper.CAFE_DESCRIPTION, position);
```

All you're doing there is put your info on a number. The number presenting the position of a item in your list.

You want to use that to get the original object and it's data out of your list.

Comment: This is for title,address,desc and those are in tbl_cafe. I want to use cafe_id from tbl_cafe to show only image that has the same id in tbl_pictures. see full [code](http://pastie.org/7147311) thanks for reply.

Comment: Yes, but all you're doing now is, if you pressed the first item in your list, you set all your data to Integer = 0.

Comment: can you hint something to make me figure out my issue?

Comment: Use something like parent.getList().get(position) instead in order to get your object and extract the correct data from that. Like i said, you're currently not putting any data of worth into your database and you should understand that if you just look at what you're doing with some attention... both the name itself as the javadoc explain perfectly fine what the position attribute is for.